# Does Pact.Net support https verification?

Tags: pact

I want to verify my pact against an API that has an https endpoint.
My request is timing out when I run the pact.
Does Pact.Net supports https verification or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be able to do this.

I'm going to guess that the https target is using a self-signed certificate. To work around that you can specify the following env vars to fix this:

> To connect to a Pact Broker that uses custom SSL cerificates, set the environment variable $SSL_CERT_FILE or $SSL_CERT_DIR to a path that contains the appropriate certificate.

(see also https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-ruby-standalone/releases)

You could enable debug logging to see what the process is doing, consult the docs on how to do that.

Comment: Isn't that only for the fetching of the pact file?

Comment: You might be right. I'd need to check the docs for verification itself, I had a feeling it was used for all of the things. Did you give it a try?

Comment: I know it has been a long time since I asked this question. I ended launching the app locally so I can use the http endpoint. Don't know if your solution work. Sorry